# Crossrider 1000 bytes per key, error about appAPI.db.get, which I do not use

Tags: crossrider

The Crossrider API on firefox does not update my view when I click the browser popup button, however in chrome it works fine. I have tried removing and installing the extension multiple times with no luck.

I got the console error in firefox as:

`<Warning: appAPI.db storage is limited to 1000 bytes per key. For larger values please use appAPI.db.async Function-name: appAPI.db.set : key=CrossriderNotifier_css>`

My code in popup.html evaluates in Chrome, however does not in Firefox.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost, you haven't done anything wrong.

The message relates to legacy code in the [Notifications plugin](http://crossrider.com/developer/plugins) and some relatively recent routines we added to assist users identify issues with their extension. In general, the message is just a warning and as long as the key does not exceed the 1000 bytes limit (which this plugin does not) then the message can be safely ignored.

However, for your own code we recommend using the [async database](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.db.async) for any data other than simple configuration data.

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: Hi, thanks! Appreciate it. However, if so, I don't quite know why the extension works in chrome, however doesn't in Firefox. In firefox, it seems that the javascript within the extension does not evaluate at all.

Comment: If the extension is not working in Firefox, it is probably unrelated to the warning you received. I'm happy to take a look at it for you if you can provide the extension id, the operating system, and the version of Firefox you are testing on. If you prefer to keep the information private please email the details to support@crossrider.com.

Comment: Thanks Shlomo, I've sent an email through. Brilliant support.

Comment: @Shlomo Is this possible to disable this warning message? I think it's can be confusing for more experienced users who look sometimes in the console ;-)

Comment: @Nicramus The message is part of the framework and cannot be disabled by user code. I'll pass on the feedback to the product team for their consideration in future releases.